# how to dynamically select an option in listbox using jquery and jstl in jsp page

Tags: java

Hi i have one listbox with some values.
 i want to select it's value based on a value in array list using JSTL.
 My code is something like that

```
<select id='lstType' name="lstType">
        <option value="abc" selected="yes">abc</option>
        <option value="bcd">bcd</option>
    <option value="efg">efg</option>
 </select>
```

and a arraylist having some object of entity class.

```
class entity{
   String str;
}
```

Now on jsp page i am fetching like this

```
$("#lstCategory option[value = <c:out value="${entity.str}"/>]").attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attr use prop

```
$('#lstType option[value="${entity.str}"]').prop("selected", "selected");
```

Edit:

Use above only if you are in jQuery 1.6 if using before version use

```
 $('#lstType option[value="${entity.str}"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this statement:

```
$('#lstType option[value="${entity.str}"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```